# What is the difference between `Synclock syncroot` and `SyncLock Me`?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, synclock

vb.Net multithreading question:

What is the difference between

```
SyncLock syncRoot  
  ''# Do Stuff  
End SyncLock
```

-and-

```
SyncLock Me  
  ''# Do Stuff  
End SyncLock
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All code that happens within a `SyncLock` block is synchronized with all other code happening within a `SyncLock` block *on the same object*. Obviously, `Me` is not the same as `syncRoot` (which is, I'm assuming, `Me.SyncRoot`, if your `Me` is an `ICollection`).

Code happening within a `SyncLock` block on one object is not going to be synchronized with code within a `SyncLock` block on a different object.

Say you have this code:

```
' happening on thread 1 '
SyncLock myColl.SyncRoot
    myColl.Add(myObject)
End SyncLock

' happening on thread 2 '
SyncLock myColl.SyncRoot
    myColl.Remove(myObject)
End SyncLock
```

The above is fine: the `Add` and `Remove` calls are synchronized, meaning they will not occur simultaneously (whichever gets called first will execute, and the second will not execute until the first is finished).

But suppose you had this instead:

```
' happening on thread 1 '
SyncLock myColl.SyncRoot
    myColl.Add(myObject)
End SyncLock

' happening on thread 2 '
SyncLock myColl ' NOTE: SyncLock on a different object '
    myColl.Remove(myObject)
End SyncLock
```

The above `Add` and `Remove` calls are **not** synchronized in any way, shape, or form. Thus there is no thread safety in the above code.

Now, why does `SyncRoot` exist? Quite simply, because it makes sense to synchronize on the *smallest* scale necessary; i.e., there is no need to synchronize code that doesn't actually need to be synchronized.

Consider this example:

```
' happening on thread 1 '
SyncLock myColl
    myColl.Add(myObject)
End SyncLock

' happening on thread 2 '
SyncLock myColl
    ' Why you would have code like this, I do not know; '
    ' this is just for illustration. '
    myColl.Name = myColl.Name.Replace("Joe", "Bill")
End SyncLock

' happening on thread 3 '
SyncLock myColl
    myColl.Name = myColl.Name.Replace("Bill", "Joe")
End SyncLock
```

In the above, you are synchronizing **more than necessary**. The `Add` call really has nothing to do with the renaming of the `myColl` object; thus the code does not need to be synchronized.

This is the idea behind the `SyncRoot` property: it gives you an object whose entire purpose is to provide a common object with which modifications to/enumerations of the collection can be synchronized. Code that *involves* the collection in some *other* way -- but which does not need to be synchronized with code that modifies or reads the contents of the collection -- should be synchronized, where appropriate, on a different object.

Answer (score 3):

If `Object.ReferenceEquals(syncRoot, Me) = True` then nothing is different. Otherwise the lock is acquired using different objects.

If your use of `syncRoot` is equivalent to `ICollection.SyncRoot` then the lock will be acquired using the same object that is used internally by the collection for its own locking. This allows you to synchronize access to enumerators. For example:

```
SyncLock collection.SyncRoot
  For Each item As Object in collection
  Next
End SyncLock
```

As a matter of convention .NET developers avoid using `Me` as the lock object. This is especially true if `Me` references as object that is visible to the public API of a class library. The reason we avoid this is because other code may use the same object to acquire a lock for a reason that conflicts with the semantic behavior you are trying to accomplish in your code. This conflict can lead to bottlenecks or even deadlocks.

It should be noted that `SyncLock` does not synchronize access to the lock object itself, but rather the code wrapped by the `SyncLock` construct. In other words, code that is guarded by a `SyncLock` using the same object is effectively serialized.

Comment: I just noticed that the word "using" appears back-to-back in the 2nd paragraph 1st sentence. It does not appear that way in the content editor textbox. Bug in SO?

Answer (score 2):

You're locking on different objects.

If other parts of your code (or internal code) sync on `SyncRoot`, which they should, then you're breaking things (i.e. introducing threading bugs) by syncing on `Me`.

You should definitely sync on `SyncRoot`--that's why it's there.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused about SyncLock.  Does synclock prevent changes to the variable that I pass to it (in this case, `syncRoot`), or does it simply lock the <em>code</em>?